# How to call Floating Button Action from another fragment while scrolling Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got Fragment that contains ViewPagerFragment and in ViewPagerFragment we are switching between two sub-fragment(each of sub-fragment has got recycler view).

Floating Action Button is implementing in Fragment and it have to be in this fragment because depends on sub-fragment that is currently showed Floating Action Button has various action.

For example:

```
if( viewpager.getCurrentItem() == 1)
   action1();
else if(view pager.getCurrentItem() == 2)
   action2();
```

And I can't pass FloatingActionButton from Fragment through Viewpager to sub-fragment. There must be other easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you put FloatingActionButton in your subfragments? This way you don't need to rely on `getCurrentItem()`. You can get current position in sub fragments if you pass position to subfragment in arguments. Share your view pager adapter  so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the floating action button to your `Activity` instead of your Fragment.

just create one FloatingActionButton in your `Activity`'s `layout` on top of your `ViewPager` via XML. You can achieve that with `CoordinatorLayout`.

After you implement the layout add an onClickListener to that button in your activity. If you need to use some data from the current fragment in a ViewPager you can get its index by calling `mviewPager.getCurrentItem()`.

Comment: Activity has got four fragments and each of this fragment's Floating Action Button has got different job

Comment: @Rafał I assume you have an activity and you have 4 fragments that have different jobs (like tabs for notification, settings etc.) and you want to show the same fab in each different fragment? Please check my edit.

Comment: In activity I've got 4 fragments and each of this(fragment) has got ViewPager in which I have two fragment. Implementing one Floating Action Button for all fragment in one Activity Is bad way I think. Especially when in every fragment and sub-fragment it has different job. Is there any other way ?